# Canvas' Image type in an Array of Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, object, canvas

Good afternoon,
I need some help with my code, I'm trying to code a map in a canvas with Hearts that the user can click on, but I want to stock these hearts into an Array to display them with a for loop.

My code's here :

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mapC");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        var Heart = function(link, posX, posY) {
            this.link = link;
            this.posX = posX;
            this.posY = posY;
            this.pic = new Image();
            this.pic.addEventListener("load", function() {
                ctx.drawImage(this.pic, this.posX, this.posY);
            }, false);
            this.pic.src = "heart.png";

        }
        Heart.prototype.heartClick = function()
        {
                document.location.href= this.link;
        }

        var heartsArray = new Array();
        heartsArray.push(new Heart("this", 40, 40));
```

And the problem is that

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap)'
```

But my "this.pic" Image is the type displayable in an array and I don't find the error, please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your callback function `this` pointing to the global object `window`.
You should save reference for `this` to new variable and then you can use it.

```
var self = this;
this.pic.addEventListener("load", function() {
    ctx.drawImage(self.pic, self.posX, self.posY);
}, false);
```

Comment: Thank you, it was the solution :)